# Android, Update app classes on the fly

Tags: android, auto-update

How can i update some classes in android (for example by injecting classes I want from a special port to the app)? or at least make an update patch so the user is have not to download whole the app.

Answer (score -1):

You can not update app classes on the fly.

All the Application classes are bundled in to apk file, and we can not apply any patch in the apk file.

you always need to build a separate new apk file if you want to provide a patch or change any class file.

Answer (score -1):

In android app's files included in apk file.  apk is a compressed file.  You need to unpack the apk file, make changes and repack it.  You may need reverse engineering skills to do.  You need special tools to do it.  But it is a proper way.